# Change Administrator Email From Code Lines in Moodle

Tags: email, smtp, moodle, administrator

Is it possible to change the moodle Administrator Email and Smtp from code editor, not the GUI? I´ve been researching and trying by my own but still not having any reault. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can update DB records, in example:

```
$admin = $DB->get_record('user',['email'=>'oldadminemail@mail.com']);
$admin->email = 'newadminemail@mail.com';
$DB->update_record('user',$admin);
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API